# ¿Por qué todas las consultas SQL dan el mismo output?

Tags: sql, python

He escrito este script en Python para hacer consultas sobre un base de datos y tratar los datos que me gustarían.

```
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("""
    -- nombre de fois que les personnes ont interragi avec les pubs, 
    SELECT  COUNT (swipe.state),swipe.eclipse_id, swipe.subscriber_id FROM swipe
  WHERE swipe.state= 2 OR swipe.state = 3 or swipe.state=5 OR swipe.state =6 or swipe.state=8 or swipe.state=9
    GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id,swipe.eclipse_id
      ORDER BY (swipe.subscriber_id) ASC
    """)
    n = cur.fetchall()
        listado_n = [{"count": elem[0], "eclipse_id": elem[1], "subscriber_id": elem[2]} for elem in n]
        print(listado_n[0]['count'])

        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("""
SELECT COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id), subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id,subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id  FROM subscriber_hashtag
  -- join para que las publicidades/eclipses que gusta un usarios estan vinculadas con las de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
  INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id = subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
  -- join para que los usarios  estan vinculadas con los de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
  LEFT OUTER JOIN swipe ON subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id = swipe.subscriber_id
  -- recobremos los "me gusta"
  WHERE swipe.state= 3 OR swipe.state = 6 or swipe.state=9
    GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id,subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id
      ORDER BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id,subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id DESC;
      """)
        p = cur.fetchall()
        listado_p = [{"count": elem[0], "hashtag_id": elem[1], "subscriber_id": elem[2]} for elem in n]
        print(listado_p[0]['count'])

        cur.execute("""
SELECT COUNT(eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id), eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id,eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id FROM eclipse_hashtag
    GROUP BY eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id, eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id
      ORDER BY eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id,eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id ASC;
    """)
        q = cur.fetchall()
        listado_q = [{"count": elem[0], "hashtag_id": elem[1], "eclipse_id": elem[2]} for elem in n]
        print(listado_q[0]['count'])
```

Le pustos en DataFrame :

```
# on récupère les valeurs brutes qui constitueron la matrice dans une "DataFrame"
df_n = pd.DataFrame(listado_n)
df_p = pd.DataFrame(listado_p)
df_q = pd.DataFrame(listado_q)
```

Pero todas me dan el mismo output :

```
df_n.head()
```

[image: first line : 1,9573,13]

```
df_p.head()
```

[image: first line : 1,9573,13]

```
df_q.head()
```

[image: 1,9573,13]

Es por decir tres veces el mismo output. Mientras que por la segunda consulta, por ejemplo, tengo en studio3T :

```
count  hashtag subscriber 
286    321     306
748    321     179
440    321     172
154    321     161
132    321     160
66     321     158
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En todos los ciclos `for` de las listas por compresión (`listado_n`, `listado_p` y `listado_q`) iteras sobre la primera consulta (`n`). Por eso todos los datos corresponden a la primera consulta.

Tienes esto:

```python
listado_p = [{"count": elem[0], "hashtag_id": elem[1], "subscriber_id": elem[2]} for elem in n]
listado_q = [{"count": elem[0], "hashtag_id": elem[1], "eclipse_id": elem[2]} for elem in n]
```

Es decir:

```python
listado_p = [{
    "count": elem[0],
     "hashtag_id": elem[1],
     "subscriber_id": elem[2]
} for elem in n]
#             ^
```

Cuando debe ser:

```python
listado_p = [{"count": elem[0], "hashtag_id": elem[1], "subscriber_id": elem[2]} for elem in p]
#                                                                                          # ^
                                                                                           # ^

listado_q = [{"count": elem[0], "hashtag_id": elem[1], "eclipse_id": elem[2]} for elem in q]
                                                                                        # ^
                                                                                        # ^
```

Es decir:

```python
listado_p = [{
  "count": elem[0],
  "hashtag_id": elem[1],
  "subscriber_id": elem[2]
} for elem in p]
#             ^
```